# Removing a particular element from an array causing an issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array where if i delete a specific element it will remove it but later if i again remove another element the newly selected element will be deleted but previously deleted element will be present as shown in fig.
[image]

refer above picture at first i removed **phone** from a array and next i removed **Account Disabled** but in the second table the previously deleted element **phone** is still present

```
var selectedOpts = $('#lstBox1 option:selected');

var text = selectedOpts.val();

var colData = [];

this.firmData.forEach(function (dta) {
    colData.push(dta.DisplayName);
})

const removeItem = value => colData.filter(item => item !== value)
    console.table(removeItem(text))
    console.log(text);
```

**UPDATE**

actual requirement

[image]

my requirement is i need to move data viceversa while moving i also want to remove it from array for now i can only append those values but i am not able to remove it from an array

> 1st column html

```
<div class="menu">
    <select multiple="multiple" id='lstBox1' >
    </select>
</div>
```

> 1st column JS code

```
 self.firmData.forEach(function (data) {                  
   $("#lstBox1").append($('<option class="items">').text(data.DisplayName).attr('value', data.DisplayName));                        
  });
```

> 2nd column HTMl

```
<div class="menu">
    <select multiple="multiple" id='lstBox2' >
    </select>
</div>
```

> 2nd column JS code

```
self.data.forEach(function (data) {
 $("#lstBox2").append($('<option class="items">').text(data.columnsexpo).attr('value', data.columnsexpo));
 });
```

> Button functions

```
 "click #btnRight": function(e){
      var selectedOpts = $('#lstBox1 option:selected');
      var text = selectedOpts.val();

      $('#lstBox2').append($(selectedOpts).clone())
      this.data.push(columnsexpo: text);
   }

  "click #btnLeft": function(e){
      var selectedOpts = $('#lstBox2 option:selected');
      var text = selectedOpts.val();

      $('#lstBox1').append($(selectedOpts).clone())
      this.data.push(columnsexpo: text);
   }
```

Comment: Can you add working fiddle?

Comment: Because removeItem doesn't change `colData`, it just filters out the items without the item you don't want and returns an array.

Comment: It looks like you are building the array (`colData`) from a different data set and removing from `colData` and not the original, so each time you run the code, it will be a new array of the data

Comment: @Valeklosse even if i remove it from original data also i am facing the same isuue

Comment: @chethu https://jsfiddle.net/2eovy46g/ I dont know if this will fit in with your current project, but I used a little jQuery, this just demos if its remove from firmData it wont have the previously remove in anymore

Answer (score 2):

Not sure from the question what you're trying to do, but this should remove the item you want from the original array. Warning - may contain bugs / errors, however Array.prototype.splice removes items from an array.

```
var selectedOpts = $('#lstBox1 option:selected');

var text = selectedOpts.val();

var colData = [];

this.firmData.forEach(function (dta) {
    colData.push(dta.DisplayName);
})

function findItem(item) {
  return item == text;
}

colData.splice(colData.findIndex(findItem), 1);
console.table(colData)
console.log(text);
```

Comment: idk what is the problem but according to your solution it should work but still i am getting the same issue

Comment: Ok, maybe you can show a little bit more code *around* these lines you've shown us . . .my suspicion is that you're calling this code in a loop, in which case the solution needs to change a bit.

Comment: the issue which i am facing revolves only around this codes

Comment: That's clearly not right, this code does not run in isolation,  think about it - there's page content, user interaction, dom state, globals in js that all have *some* effect on this code, if we can't find the issue here, then we'll need to look at a few more lines of code to understand what you're doing that may be causing the issue.

Comment: see my question i had updated everything that is my actual requirement

Answer (score 0):

`.filter` don't remove item from array

To remove item in your array you can do

```
colData.splice(colData.indexOf(text), 1)
```

Live demo

```js
var colData = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

const removeItem = value => {
  let arr = colData.splice(colData.indexOf(value), 1);
  return arr;
}

removeItem('a');
removeItem('d');

console.log(colData);
```

Comment: still i am facing the same issue same as my question removing current element and adding previously deleted element